# "Error: Could not start the command" when trying to view externally as a PDF

Tags: pdf, viewers

I'm using TeXstudio, and everything compiles fine within the application, but when I click on the "external viewer" button, it says "Error: Could not start the command." It's worked before and opened a PDF in my Google Chrome tab, so I'm not sure what's going wrong now.

Comment: Could you check: Options/Configure TeXstudio/Compilations and more precisely your extern PDF viewer.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I was able to figure it out! Thank you!